# Count Occurrences of Intrinsics Using Esprima

Tags: javascript, node.js, lexical-analysis, esprima

I am working on an application that allows user-submitted web-pages with embedded JavaScript code.

I would like to learn more about how my users are writing their JavaScript code, by building a map of common JavaScript intrinsics (built in objects) which shows the occurrence of each in user generated code.

Assume I have a JS file from a user's webpage:

Main.js

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { myArrs.push(new Array()); }
let myObj = new Object();
```

I would like a script that can generate the following output:

```
Array: 10
Object: 1
```

I have attempted to do this using both regex and string traversal, but this does not account for the case where an item is used in an iteration. Simple string traversal would yield me with:

```
Array: 1
Object: 1
```

Which is not correct.

Esprima seems to provide a solution to this as it can perform syntactic analysis since it is a JS parser. I have attempted to use `esprima.parseScript(input, config, delegate)` to generate a tree and than traverse the tree but the output still does not take into account iterations.

Here is the output from my attempt at parsing this information using Esprima:

```
{
    "type": "Program",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ForStatement",
            "init": {
                "type": "VariableDeclaration",
                "declarations": [
                    {
                        "type": "VariableDeclarator",
                        "id": {
                            "type": "Identifier",
                            "name": "i"
                        },
                        "init": {
                            "type": "Literal",
                            "value": 0,
                            "raw": "0"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "kind": "let"
            },
            "test": {
                "type": "BinaryExpression",
                "operator": "<",
                "left": {
                    "type": "Identifier",
                    "name": "i"
                },
                "right": {
                    "type": "Literal",
                    "value": 10,
                    "raw": "10"
                }
            },
            "update": {
                "type": "UpdateExpression",
                "operator": "++",
                "argument": {
                    "type": "Identifier",
                    "name": "i"
                },
                "prefix": false
            },
            "body": {
                "type": "BlockStatement",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "ExpressionStatement",
                        "expression": {
                            "type": "CallExpression",
                            "callee": {
                                "type": "MemberExpression",
                                "computed": false,
                                "object": {
                                    "type": "Identifier",
                                    "name": "myArrs"
                                },
                                "property": {
                                    "type": "Identifier",
                                    "name": "push"
                                }
                            },
                            "arguments": [
                                {
                                    "type": "NewExpression",
                                    "callee": {
                                        "type": "Identifier",
                                        "name": "Array"
                                    },
                                    "arguments": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "VariableDeclaration",
            "declarations": [
                {
                    "type": "VariableDeclarator",
                    "id": {
                        "type": "Identifier",
                        "name": "myObj"
                    },
                    "init": {
                        "type": "NewExpression",
                        "callee": {
                            "type": "Identifier",
                            "name": "Object"
                        },
                        "arguments": []
                    }
                }
            ],
            "kind": "let"
        }
    ],
    "sourceType": "script"
}
```

I was not able to find this answer on SO already - it seems like this is a useful problem to solve but requires a bit of knowledge in lexical analysis tools such as Esprima.

Comment: You cannot do this using lexical static analysis. You will need to run the code to see how many array it generates. You can inject counters into the AST for that, similar to code coverage tools.

Comment: @Bergi are you saying you don't think its possible to do this without invoking the interpreter and injecting counters? E.g. I have to run the code? I was hoping to figure out a way to do this with a parsing tool like Esprima that doesn't run the code because that could potentially present security issues.

Comment: Yes. I even could *prove* that it's impossible without interpreting the code if I wanted.